# Increasing Subdomain Limit

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain

I've a Linux hosting but it allows me only have 5 subdomains. But I want to give my members their own subdomains.

What I need is to redirect memberName.mySite.com to mySite.com/profile.php?id=memberName

Like I said before, I can to it through cPanel for only 5 members because this is my limit. Can I do this with .htaccess or something else?

I did try a lot of code but couldn't accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

If it is your web host that limits you to 5 sub domains you will not be able to alter that programatically or via cpanel.

Comment: for sure? this is bad for me. can you redirect mySite.com/memberName to mySite.com/profile.php?id=memberName? but still, mySite.com/homepage to mySite.com/index.php is it possible?

Comment: You can do this using .htaccess rules (presuming you are using apache as the web server). See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html for an overview. Google will be your friend on the exact format for the rules you need to write as well.